# Query Import Range not updating when script runs automatically - error loading

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have a script to paste the raw data from a csv received by email. When the raw data is pasted on the sheet, I expected that another sheet with a **query import range formula** updates automatically with the new data.

I have a second script to read data from a pivot table that comes from the sheet with those formulas. However when it tries to read the data from the pivot table I get the error *Exception: The number of rows in the range must be at least 1.*. This happens because my variable numRows is equal to zero.

When I open the g-doc manually I see an error on the sheet with the formulas mentioned: error loading.
However, after really a few seconds that I open the gdoc, the range updates almost instantaneally without any problem, and If I manually run the script after this happening it runs without any problem.

How can I make sure that after updating the raw data I don't get the formulas stucked on error loading? I would like to run the script automatically and not manually. Any tip is more than welcome.

Notes:

1. I've tried already every type of recalculations but didn't work (on change, on change and every hour, on change and every minute)
2. The raw data has arround 2300 rows
3. The formula I am using is the following: `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1OpF8gcrV1Yj8bYP1j5PsHM4VRw2pKZOUmJf6VxGeFdY","raw_data!A2:G"), "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col2 is not null order by Col4 asc, Col1 asc, Col5 asc",0)`

```
function sending_emails(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OpF8gcrV1Yj8bYP1j5PsHM4VRw2pKZOUmJf6VxGeFdY");
  var today = new Date();
  
  
  if(today.getDay() != 6 && today.getDay() != 0){      


  //Sending emails to reps:

  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of sending_emails");
  var aux = data_sheet.getRange("B3:B").getValues();
  
  var startRow = 3; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = aux.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log('numRows' + numRows); 
  // Fetch the range of cells 
  var dataRange = data_sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5); //I get the error here because startRow = 3 and I get numRows = 0
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();


  for (var a in data) {
    var row = data[a];
    var message = row[3]; 
    var emailAddress = row[0];
    Logger.log('emailAddress'+ emailAddress);

    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress, 
      subject: 'Task Manager', 
      htmlBody: message,
      cc: row[4]

    });
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The issue is likely with `IMPORTRANGE`

The class of functions `IMPORTHTML`, `IMPORTRANGE` etc have been the subject of many questions about auto updating - this approach generally seems to be quite flaky. I can't find it documented anywhere but I suspect that these functions stop calculating when they are closed. Or if a recalculation happens, for some reason they are not authorized because they are no longer linked to a user session.

That said, although I don't use this approach, I have tested it various times and it seems to work for me, though I know there are many people for whom it does not.

Some people have found that by removing all protections and making the sheet public removes errors, though in my experience its just best to remove formulae from the equation (no pun intended).

#### Suggested fix

In your chain of `Mail > Apps Script > Sheet > FORMULA > Sheet`.

Change it to `Mail > Apps Script > Sheet > Apps Script > Sheet`.

I don't have your source data to test with, but to implement your query in Apps Script would look something like this:

```js
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR ID");
const dataRange = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange("A2:G");
const data = dataRange.getValues()

const filteredData = data.filter(row => row[1] !== "")
```

You could potentially sort the data with formulae once it has been imported with the script.

---

**TLDR**: Chaining `IMPORTRANGE` may work sometimes, but it doesn't seem very reliable. In my opinion, you are better off moving everything to Apps Script at this point.

Comment: Thanks a lot @iansedano! I would love to give you positive feedback but as I  am quite recent in the platform I am not able to give you at the moment. I will give you in he future. Changing the import range actually worked but it is as you said, doesn't seem so reliable. I will try to change the formulas in apps script.